# Why harbor auth mode is disabled?

Tags: authentication, harbor

I wanted to switch Harbor from database mode to LDAP. unfortunately it was disabled when I go to Administration\Configuration\Auth mode
What to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clear out all users except admin/anonymous. If there is any foreign key association, it is also necessary to remove the association

You can also follow these instructions if above solution doesn't work: https://github.com/goharbor/harbor/wiki/harbor-faqs#authentication